# Monotonic, smooth (cts. 2nd derivative), area-preserving interpolator

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, applications

I'm a physicist looking for a way to get an interpolator from (1D) binned data which preserves area, is smooth (has cts. 2nd derivs preferably) and is monotonic.

Binned data sets are ones where one knows the integrated value in lots of small ranges (bins) but not how that area is distributed within the bin.

Comment: Are the bins equally spaced? Are the bins arranged on a line or on a grid? (1D, 2D). Is the data guaranteed to be monotonic?

Comment: The data usually has a single global maximum. But not necessarily. But I guess one can assume it's piece-wise monotonic. 1D uneven bins.

Comment: How about akima? It's available in Matlab and Scipy and I think gsl.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a practical solution. I simply edited the binned values I fitted to, in order to reproduce the real binned data. Basically, for each bin, I integrated the interpolator; the bin value would then be area/bin_width. I then updated the data I fit to by fit_data = fit_data + (real_bin_val - area/bin_width). So the fit data and actual data is different. Repeating this converges. I used gsl_interp_steffens from GNOME C++.

It would be interesting if there were more theoretical/mathematical methods.